# What tool do you use for counting lines of source code in Visual Studio Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

I know there are quite a few line count tools around. Is there something simple that's not a part some other big package that you use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Slick Edit Gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=90) has a nice report breaking it down by lines of code, whitespace and comments. The plug-in is free and relatively small.

Comment: I've used that too. It has a pie chart showing what proportion of each type of line is used in the code.

Comment: Link broken, and the product appears to no longer exist (perhaps part of slickedit now?)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if it's not a direct answer but these days I much prefer to use code metric tools or profilers rather than lines of code.  [Ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm) and [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com) are two that immediately come to mind.

It's just that these tools allow you to get a real grasp on the size/complexity of your software, lines of code is a very primitive metric.

Comment: I realize it is a primitive metric. I just wanted to know a ball park figure without drawing any major conclusions from it.

Answer (score 2):

I use this Python script:

```
import os, sys
total_count = 0
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
  dirs[:] = [ # prune search path
    dir for dir in dirs
    if dir.lower() not in ('.svn', 'excludefrombuild')]
  for filename in filenames:
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() in ('.cpp', '.h'):
      fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
      count = 0
      for line in open(fullname): count += 1
      total_count += count
      print count, fullname
print total_count
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 Team Developer or Team Suite edition, you [can get them directly](http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/10/27/how-to-count-the-lines-of-code-loc-in-your-application-using-visual-studio.aspx) in Visual Studio using [Code Metrics](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/vs2008/4773).

Answer (score 1):

You could use find and wc from this relatively small package, http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Like

```
find . -name *.cs -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Or, if you have a linux machine handy you can mount the drive and do it like that, and it'll give you a ballpark figure. You can complexify to remove comments, etc. But given that you just want a ballpark figure, shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Project in Solution explorer and select "Calculate Code Metrics".

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this works in VS08 ... [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have also used this simple C# made tool.

http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/c-visual-basic-and-c-net-line-count-utility-version-2/

Answer (score 0):

Exact Magic's StodioTools package (free) shows Executable LoC among other metrics. This is a plug-in to VisualStudio 2008.

Comment: [Supplier's site](http://submain.com/productsstudiotools.aspx) reports: _StudioTools is retired and will no longer be offered for download or supported._

Answer (score 0):

Project Line Counter is pretty cool, but you need an updated .reg file for VS 2008 and later.  I have a .reg file for Visual Studio 2010 on my website: http://www.onemanmmo.com/index.php?cmd=newsitem&comment=news.1.41.0  There's some instructions in the discussion at CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/linecount.aspx with info on getting it to run with Visual Studio 2008.